# React Create Application production build and CSS variables in IE11

Tags: reactjs, webpack, internet-explorer-11, css-variables

I would like to know how to get rid of CSS variables in a production build. The fact is that I need to build a project for IE11 in which CSS variables are not supported. My project was created using React Create App and I can't do npm run eject. How can you set up a production build so that in the initial heart rate of the style, instead of variables, there would be their values?

Don't offer `css-vars-ponyfill`, it takes a very long time to load a page in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make CSS variables work in IE is using a polyfill. If you don't want to use css-vars-ponyfill, you can try [ie11CustomProperties](https://github.com/nuxodin/ie11CustomProperties) or [css-variables-polyfill](https://github.com/aaronbarker/css-variables-polyfill).

If you don't want to use a polyfill, I think you can only edit the CSS styles manually to add CSS fallbacks to support IE11. Something like this:

```
body {
  --text-color: red;
}
body {
  color: red;
  color: var(--text-color);
}
```

Comment: Hi @CaptainNigorro Is there any update about the issue? I am glad to help if you have any other questions.